# Using a dictionary, practice code

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.3

I apologize for my earlier questions as they were vague and difficult to answer. I am still fairly new to programming and am still learning the ins and outs of it all. So please bear with me. Now to the background information. I am using python 3.3.0. I have it loaded onto the Eclipse IDE and that is what I am using to write the code and test it in.

Now to the question: I am trying to learn how to create and use dictionaries. As such my assignment is to create a price matching code that through user interface will not only be able to search through a dictionary for the items (which are the keys and the locations and prices which are the values associated with the keys.) So far I have created a user interface that will run through well enough without any errors however (at least within the IDE) When I run through and input all of the prompts the empty dictionary is not updated and as such I cannot then make a call into the dictionary for the earlier input.

I have the code I have written so far below, and would like if someone could tell me if I am doing things correctly. And if there are any better ways of going about this. I am still learning so more detailed explanations around code jargon would be useful.

```
print("let's Price match") 
decition = input("Are you adding to the price match list?") 
if decition == "yes": 
    pricematchlist = {"Snapple":["Tops",99]} 
    location = input("Now tell me where you shopped") 
    item = input("Now what  was the item") 
    price = input("Now how much was the item") 
    int(price) 
    pricematchlist[item]=location,price 
    print(pricematchlist) 
else:  
    pricematchlist = {"Snapple":["Tops",99]}  
    reply = input("Ok so you want to search up a previous price?") 
    if reply == "yes": 
        search = input("What was the item?")
        pricematchlist.item(search)
```

Comment: This question as written would be a better fit for code review.  If you have a specific problem area please point that out and we may be able to help.

Comment: Please ask a single question, not two completely different things. If you need help getting your dictionary to work, then try to write a short, working example that reproduces the problem. If you want feedback on **working** (!) code, [codereview.SE] is indeed the right place, but this doesn't seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 2):

These are a few minor changes. For dictionaries: you are using them correctly.

```
print("let's Price match") 
pricemathlist = {"Snapple":["Tops", 99]} # assign it here
decition = input("Are you adding to the price match list?").lower() #"Yes"-->"yes"
if decition == "yes": 
    # pricematchlist = {"Snapple":["Tops",99]}
    # If this whole code block is called repeatedly, you don't want to reassign it
    location = input("Now tell me where you shopped") 
    item = input("Now what  was the item") 
    price = int(input("Now how much was the item"))
    # int(price) does nothing with reassigning price
    pricematchlist[item]=location,price 
    print(pricematchlist) 
else:    
    reply = input("Ok so you want to search up a previous price?").lower()
    if reply == "yes": 
        search = input("What was the item?")
        print pricematchlist[search] # easier way of accessing a value
```

Comment: Thank you this helps alot. But quick question. How do I get the program to actually add, through only user interface, the new value. Let's say that I went to Walmart and got a mountain dew for like 98 cents. So I access the program and add in the location the item and the price. How will it then add the new key as well as the values into the dictionary. Also any way I can add a dollar symbol to the money. Please and thank you.

Comment: To use the dollar sign, you'd have to make the number into a string. To create a new key, value pair: `pricematchlist['Mountain Dew'] = '$0.98'`.